# How does orchard handle modules

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, module, orchardcms

I'm looking at building my own modular MVC4 app, I like how orchard handles modules and I would like to take design queues from it, maybe even copy it entirely (why reinvent the wheel?).

I've read [this](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/How-Orchard-works) and I've looked through the source and I have a small understanding.

However if someone familiar with the system could explain how orchard loads, unloads and keeps track of modules I would be very grateful.

Comment: You'll want to look at extension loaders. They implement various strategies that may be of interest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bertrand's comment led me to this http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-module-loader-and-dynamic-compilation

It has a fair explanation of how it handles module loading.

Comment: Do you know which `class` and `function` does the loading? Thanks for sharing.